# Split Rows in Power Query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

How would I be able to group rows evenly between a a dynamic number of a cell?

1000 rows, need to split into 10, and for each row it will like the below

```
Index | Group
1     | 1
99    | 1
101   | 2
200   | 3
500   | 6
900   | 10
1000  | 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some more detail? It's not very clear what you need help with.

In PowerQuery, you could Group Rows by creating an index column, then creating a custom column that adds the group number (IE: if [Index] <= 1000 then 10 else if [Index] <= 900 then 9... etc) and finally group by the group number.  You could also use some algebra to automatically determine the group number using the modulo operator with a defined # of rows variable.  Of course, when you group rows, it performs aggregations and you lose your other data in the query.

I'd be happy to provide more detailed steps, but I would need more information in your problem description.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as binning.

```
Function getBucket(rng As Range) As String
    Dim strReturn As String

    Select Case rng.Value
        Case 0 To 100
            strReturn = "1"
        Case 101 To 200
             strReturn = "2"
        Case 201 To 300
             strReturn = "3"
        Case 301 To 400
             strReturn = "4"
        Case 401 To 500
             strReturn = "5"
        Case 501 To 600
             strReturn = "6"
        Case 601 To 700
             strReturn = "7"
        Case 701 To 800
             strReturn = "9"
        Case 801 To 900
             strReturn = "9"
        Case Else
             strReturn = "10"
    End Select
    getBin = strReturn
End Function
```

[image]

Change the code to suit your specific needs.  It seems like the 900 should go in the '9' bin, not the '10' bin, like you are showing, but you can easily change the code to do it that way, if you want.